# Ошибка при добавлении зависимости во flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при добавлении зависимости get: во flutter ничего не происходит. А при импорте "import'package:get/get.dart';" в главный файл редактор предлагает добавить данную зависимость но вылезает ошибка "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined".Кто то может встречался с подобной проблемой, как пофиксить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прописать в терминале `flutter pub get`, затем подождите пока возьмутся пакеты и тогда среда разработки предложит вам импортировать пакет.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему просто переносом кода в новый проект и в нем уже подключил зависимость. Так и не смог разобраться в чем была проблема, но при обновлении зависимостей, просто была бесконечная загрузка...

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).